# Gradle Zip Task running forever depending on destination directory

Tags: gradle, groovy

So I came across this weird behavior and can't think of a reason for it and couldn't find a solution for it.
I have a Zip task in my `build.gradle` that should zip up everything in a directory and put the zip in the same directory. It looks like:

```
task combinedFilesZip(type: Zip) {
    from "${buildDir}/Release-Artifacts/Release-1"
    archiveName = "${project.name}-${project.version}-AllFiles.zip"
    destinationDir = file("${buildDir}/Release-Artifacts/Release-1/")
}
```

This task essentially doesn't terminate and goes on forever but upon inspecting the file system I can see the zip being created but it's size is ranging in the 2-3 GB which is absolutely wrong. I get an error when trying to unzip this artifact

I then changed: `destinationDir = file("${buildDir}/"`

And then suddenly the zip task executes almost instantly and all the right things are in the zip. Is there an explanation for it? And is there a way to put the created zip in the same directory that is being zipped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a bug in zip task. While creating the archive file, zip task read files as byte array chunks from the directory and write the zip file it created to the same directory. And starts reading and compressing the zip file it creates. This creates an endless loop.

I tested this with gradle 4.10.2 and It does not behave like this. You may try to upgrade Your gradle. If You can't do that, You can try excluding zip file name in the zip task like below

```
task combinedFilesZip(type: Zip) {
    from ("${buildDir}/Release-Artifacts/Release-1"){
       exclude "${project.name}-${project.version}-AllFiles.zip"
    }
    archiveName = "${project.name}-${project.version}-AllFiles.zip"
    destinationDir = file("${buildDir}/Release-Artifacts/Release-1/")
}
```

Comment: Perfect! That worked. I didn't think that it would pick up the zip it just created and recursively try that. I should have tried it with a different destination directory. 
And I was running Gradle 4.10 and encountered it.

Comment: @samz_manu It looks like a bug definitely.  FYI 4.10.2 does not do this.